# Q: How get sum value dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key-value

i'm trying my code. I'm confused..How to combine these 2 dictionaries so that the value of the results is like this expected?
For every chart like this  and total price get like this :

```
[{'Cherries': 1, 'Blueberries': 2, 'Banana': 3, 'Avocado': 2, 'Blackberries': 2}, {'Apple': 6, 'Avocado': 5, 'Banana': 3, 'Blackberries': 10, 'Blueberries': 12, 'Cherries': 7, 'Date Fruit': 14, 'Grapes': 15, 'Guava': 8, 'Jackfruit': 7, 'Kiwifruit': 9}]
output 70
[{'Cherries': 4, 'Blackberries': 2, 'Avocado': 2, 'Blueberries': 2}, {'Apple': 6, 'Avocado': 5, 'Banana': 3, 'Blackberries': 10, 'Blueberries': 12, 'Cherries': 7, 'Date Fruit': 14, 'Grapes': 15, 'Guava': 8, 'Jackfruit': 7, 'Kiwifruit': 9}]
output 82
[{'Avocado': 1, 'Blueberries': 2, 'Cherries': 3, 'Banana': 2, 'Apple': 1, 'Blackberries': 1}, {'Apple': 6, 'Avocado': 5, 'Banana': 3, 'Blackberries': 10, 'Blueberries': 12, 'Cherries': 7, 'Date Fruit': 14, 'Grapes': 15, 'Guava': 8, 'Jackfruit': 7, 'Kiwifruit': 9}]
output 72
```

For my code :

```
fruits = ['Apple','Avocado','Banana','Blackberries','Blueberries','Cherries','Date Fruit','Grapes','Guava','Jackfruit','Kiwifruit']
prices = [6,5,3,10,12,7,14,15,8,7,9]
chart = ['Blueberries','Blueberries','Grapes','Apple','Apple','Apple','Blueberries','Guava','Jackfruit','Blueberries','Jackfruit']
d1 = dict(zip(fruits,prices))
fruit_price = None
dcounter = {}
for i in chart:
    if i in dcounter:
        dcounter[i] +=1
    else:
        dcounter[i] =1
#print(dcounter)
fruit_price = {}
for i, j in d1.items():
    for x, y in dcounter.items():
        if i == x:
            fruit_price[i]=(j*y)
#print(fruit_price)

def total_price(dcounter,fprice):
    total = 0
    for i in fruit_price.values():
        total+= i
    return total
total_price(dcounter,fruit_price)
```

And i wanna code for dcounter and fruit_price enter in function (def total_price)
Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are trying to accomplish. What is the input? What is the difference between `fruits` and `charts`? What is `prices`, how is it linked to the rest of the inputs? Please describe your code, copy/paste it is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear at all, however, I managed to get an understanding of the problem.

First of all, your input contains 2 dictionaries, one is the `shopping_list`, the other is the `prices`.

So, first think first, extract the two for clarity

```
list_of_dicts = [{'Cherries': 1, 'Blueberries': 2, 'Banana': 3, 'Avocado': 2, 'Blackberries': 2}, {'Apple': 6, 'Avocado': 5, 'Banana': 3, 'Blackberries': 10, 'Blueberries': 12, 'Cherries': 7, 'Date Fruit': 14, 'Grapes': 15, 'Guava': 8, 'Jackfruit': 7, 'Kiwifruit': 9}]
shopping_list = list_of_dicts[0]
prices = list_of_dicts[1]
```

Now, it is easy to iterate over the shopping list, get the amount of item you buy, and multiply that amount for the price of the item.

```
def get_bill(shopping_list, prices):
    bill = 0
    for item, amount in shopping_list.items():
        bill += prices[item]*amount
    return bill

get_bill(shopping_list, prices)
#70
```

Now that the procedure is clear, you can add the first step in the function body, and pass a single input to it.

```
def get_bill(list_of_dicts):
    shopping_list = list_of_dicts[0]
    prices = list_of_dicts[1]
    bill = 0
    for item, amount in shopping_list.items():
        bill += prices[item]*amount
    return bill
```